# Processing a tex file automatically

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I'm currently writing in markdown and converting using Pandoc, but there are additional replacements that I want to do, as well as fixing some of what pandoc does that I don't like. Does anyone know the best approach to writing a script or somehow automating the process of find+replace using regex?

I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, but it would be great just to get a hint as to what kind of thing I need (e.g. which programming language, if I need to go down that route).

Comment: This sounds more like a shell-scripting question.  I'd look into using `sed` (or `awk`, which I don't really use, but it is powerful), or `perl` if you like.

Comment: One easy command is `rpl` (replace)  in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your needs are not easily met with sed/awk you can use the pandocfilters library for python. Be sure to check out the [pandoc scripting tutorial](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) for general information and information specific to pandocfilters.

Github repo: [pandocfilters](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters)